# How do I create a button with a background colour of my choice in blackberry 10 cascades?

Tags: blackberry-10

I want to create a button with a background colour of my choice in blackberry 10 cascades.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple to create your own buttons, once you get used to qml at least :)

Below is an example of a custom button, place it in a file such as CustomButton.qml.  You could also use a property to be able to pass through a colour making it easily reusable.

```
Container {
    property alias text: label.text

    signal clicked()  //emits a clicked signal.
        gestureHandlers: [
        TapHandler {
                onTapped: {
                    clicked();
            }
        }
    ]

    layout: DockLayout {
    }

    Container {
        background: Color.Red
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
        Container {
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
            topPadding: 10
            bottomPadding: 15
            leftPadding: 20
            rightPadding: 20
            Label {
                id: label
                text: "demo"
                textStyle {
                    base: tsLabel.style
                }
                topMargin: 0
                bottomMargin: 0
                topPadding: 0
                bottomPadding: 0
            }
        }
    }

    attachedObjects: [
        TextStyleDefinition {
            id: tsLabel
            base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BodyText
            fontSize: FontSize.Small
            color: Color.White
            fontWeight: FontWeight.W100
        }
    ]
}
```

To use this in your main page you would just do the following:

```
CustomButton {
    text: "my button"
    onClicked: {
        //do code
    }
}
```

To enhance on this you could add an animation or colour change in the onTapped function.  You could also use a 9patch for the button image, using imagePaint instead of Color.Red.

Comment: thanks for this....but I want to create this button using qt c++...can anyone help ?

Comment: I don't have any code handy, but I would still create the button "class" as above in qml (keeping general visual styling seperate from the business logic) and then in c++ create a new instance of the custom button so you can add it to the page.